# How to catch the elements of JSON list which is sent by back-end method in Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

I'm doing Java web application. A back-end method sends a JSON list but how can I access it from front-end?
This is a sample of the JSON list which is returning from back-end method.

```
[ { "completedDate" : null,
    "completenessLevel" : 0,
    "priority" : 0,
    "startedDate" : 1405621923000,
    "toBeCompleted" : 1405621923000,
    "userName" : "prasad",
    "userTaskDiscription" : "Task1 desc",
    "userTaskId" : 25,
    "userTaskName" : "Task1"
  },
  { "completedDate" : null,
    "completenessLevel" : 0,
    "priority" : 0,
    "startedDate" : 1405704875000,
    "toBeCompleted" : 1405704875000,
    "userName" : "prasad",
    "userTaskDiscription" : "Task2 desc",
    "userTaskId" : 26,
    "userTaskName" : "Task2"
  }
]
```

Comment: did you try `data[0].userName`, it will return you `prasad` and so on

Comment: Thanks Mritunjay and Ganesh. Both of your answers are working. Now my task is to display them in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery to make your JSON requests you can access JSON list in the success method of the ajax function. Your success method could like

```
success:function(response){
 console.log(response[0].userName);
}
```

This would print **prasad** from the first object in the JSON list.